# Extracting desired field in powershell from a command output

Tags: windows, powershell

I am in the process of writing a powershell script, as part of which, I need to find out the flavour of Linux of the target machine, and based on which flavour I get, I need to execute command subsequently.

To know the linux type, I have executed the command:

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

An example output of which looks like:

NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server" VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)" ID="rhel" ID_LIKE="fedora" VARIANT="Server" VARIANT_ID="server" VERSION_I
D="7.6" PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)" ANSI_COLOR="0;31" CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:se
rver" HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"  REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Li
nux 7" REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6 REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux" REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.6"

I need to get the **NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"** or more specifically **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server** portion of the output. Similarly the ouput might be Debian or CentOS or SUSE in the **NAME=** portion.

I tried the following if $output is the whole of the above output:

1. `$output.NAME`
2. `$abc = -split $Output; Write-Host $abc[0] + $abc[1]`
3. `findstr`
4. `Select-String`
   and a couple of more things

But none of them work. Can someone help?

Comment: Which patterns did you use with `findstr`/`Select-String`?

Comment: Does `if ($output -match 'NAME=\"([^\"]+)\"') { $result = $matches[1] }` help?  `$result` should contain "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server" if `$output` is a string (as shown above).

Comment: The -match operator stores the result in the $matches variable. Using the correct regex like leeharvey1 suggested, you can easyly get the desired result. -tom

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen, I used both, did not get the desired result with either.

Comment: @leeharvey1 I will try this and get back.

Comment: @justlearning Right, but I was asking what _pattern_ you used - what string did you pass as an argument to `findstr` or `Select-String`?

Comment: @leeharvey1, tried what you mentioned above. get this error:
Message: [Cannot index into a null array. ]

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen sorry I looked for what exact command and options I used along with finstr and select-string, I don't seem to have captured it anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

Regex one way to do this, another way is to use `ConvertFrom-String` which has the option to supply a template. Eg.

```
$Template = 'NAME="{Name:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server}" VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)" ID="rhel" ID_LIKE="fedora" VARIANT="Server" VARIANT_ID="server" VERSION_ID="7.6" PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)" ANSI_COLOR="0;31" CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:server" HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"  REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7" REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6 REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Eterprise Linux" REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.6"'

$TestData = 'NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server" VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)" ID="rhel" ID_LIKE="fedora" VARIANT="Server" VARIANT_ID="server" VERSION_ID="7.6" PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)" ANSI_COLOR="0;31" CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:server" HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"  REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7" REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6 REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Eterprise Linux" REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.6"'
$TestData2 = 'NAME="Ubuntu" VERSION="20.04 (Maipo)" ID="debian" ID_LIKE="fedora" VARIANT="Server" VARIANT_ID="server" VERSION_ID="7.6" PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)" ANSI_COLOR="0;31" CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:server" HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"  REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7" REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6 REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Eterprise Linux" REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.6"'
$TestData3 = 'NAME="Centos" VERSION="7.654 (Maipo)" ID="rhel" ID_LIKE="fedora" VARIANT="Server" VARIANT_ID="server" VERSION_ID="7.6" PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)" ANSI_COLOR="0;31" CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:server" HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"  REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7" REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6 REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Eterprise Linux" REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.6"'
$TestData4 = 'NAME="Arch Linux" VERSION="24.6 (Maipo)" ID="rhel" ID_LIKE="fedora" VARIANT="Server" VARIANT_ID="server" VERSION_ID="7.6" PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)" ANSI_COLOR="0;31" CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:server" HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"  REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7" REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6 REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Eterprise Linux" REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.6"'
$TestData,$TestData2,$TestData3,$TestData4 | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $_ | 
        ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $Template
    }
```

Output:

```
Name
----
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
Ubuntu
Centos
Arch Linux
```

EDIT: Here's a regex variant:

```
$Regex = '.*="(.*)"\sVERSION='
$TestData,$TestData2,$TestData3,$TestData4 |
    ForEach-Object {
        [void]($_ -match $Regex)
        $Matches.1
    }
```

Output:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
Ubuntu
Centos
Arch Linux
```

Comment: Hi @PMental, I have edited my original post to make it more clear. The cat command will be run on one target server at a time, so the "for each" portion might not be needed. I just need to get the OS flavour from the "NAME=" portion of the output, store it in a variable and use it to run the next command (which of course will be specific to the flavour of Linux). So we might need a change to your answer :)

Comment: That's what my answer does? It will capture anything from the name portion, and I provided 4 different examples showing it working with different names. What part isn't working?

Comment: 1/4:
the code looks like this:
$Template = 'NAME="{Name:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server}" VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)" ID="rhel" ID_LIKE="fedora" VARIANT="Server" VARIANT_ID="server" VERSION_ID="7.6" PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)" ANSI_COLOR="0;31" CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:server" HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"  REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7" REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6 REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Eterprise Linux" REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.6"',

Comment: 2/4:
the code continued:
$Output = (Invoke-SSHCommand -SSHSession $Session -Command 'cat /etc/os-release').Output    
    Write-Host $Output
    $os_type = $Output | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $_ | 
        ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $Template
    }

    Write-Host $os_type

Comment: 3/4:
output looks like this:
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server" VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)" ID="rhel" ID_LIKE="fedora" VARIANT="Server" VARIANT_ID="server" VERSION_I
D="7.6" PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)" ANSI_COLOR="0;31" CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:se
rver" HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"  REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Li
nux 7" REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6 REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux" REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.6"

Comment: 4/4:
the error:
Message: [ConvertFrom-String appears to be having trouble parsing your data using the template you've provided. We'd love to take a lo
ok at what went wrong, if you'd like to share the data and template used to parse it. We've saved these files to C:\Users\acnadmin\App
Data\Local\Temp\2\b0bbkgpl.izj.input.txt and C:\Users\superadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\b0bbkgpl.izj-0.template.txt - feel free to attach 
them in a mail to psdmfb@microsoft.com. We will review all submissions, although we can't guarantee a response. ]

Comment: Hi @pmental, please check comments above

Comment: The code and output is very hard to read in the comments, could you put it in pastebin and post a link to that instead?

Comment: @justlearning Tagging in a comment just in case as well.